# How to add annotations to the reified class in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, annotations

I need to create a class which implements an interface and also has an annotation, and later pass an instance of this class to some API implemented in Java.

With Clojure, I could reify the interface and get an instance like this:

```
(reify MyInterface (method1 [this] ...))
```

However, `reify` doesn't seem to accept annotations. How may I work around this?

Comment: Probably via runtime bytecode manipulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all `reify` returns an object not a class. If you need to generate a class with annotations, you will need to use [`gen-class`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/gen-class) as shown below (the example shows adding a Deprecated annotation to the class):

```
(gen-class :name ^{java.lang.Deprecated true} MyClass
   ...)
```

Also, you can use [`deftype`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/deftype):

```
(deftype ^{java.lang.Deprecated true} MyClass 
  ...)
```

Comment: `reify` returns an object when you call it, but creates a class when you **compile** it. As there are frameworks out there that use reflection on objects you pass to them, it could be useful for `reify` to put annotations on its methods (or on the class itself). As you note, this is in fact not possible, but to say that `reify` doesn't create a class is false.